# php mailer smtp connect() failed to gmail

Tags: php

I have tried to send mail through gmail. I have seen other people solutions but it didn't work for me. What is the problem in my code?

Here is my output error

> 2017-06-27 13:53:54 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP o131sm2910537wmd.26 - gsmtp
>   2017-06-27 13:53:54 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
>   2017-06-27 13:53:54 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [213.55.85.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250 SMTPUTF8
>   2017-06-27 13:53:54 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
>   2017-06-27 13:53:55 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>   SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
>   2017-06-27 13:53:55 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
>   2017-06-27 13:53:55 
>   2017-06-27 13:53:55 
>   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
>   Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Here is the source code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "hajiman00@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxx";
$mail->setFrom('hajiman00@gmail.com', 'Support From HITD');
$mail->addAddress('hjibril37@gmail.com', 'Hassen Jibril');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->msgHTML("MUKERA 123");
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: By default gmail doesn't allow smtp connections, you have to enable it on the gmail config.

Comment: I have already enabled IMAP

Comment: Read this gmail thread. You have to enable from gmail settings. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: I have  already enabled Less secure app

Comment: _“I have already enabled IMAP”_ - good for you, but that does not make 587 the right port for IMAP connections ...

Comment: use PORT : 465 and connection : ssl

Comment: Also relevant: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: Have your tried enabling extention `extension=php_openssl.dll`

Comment: openssl is enabled by default since I am using wamp 3.0.6

Comment: any other solutions out there guys?

Comment: which PHPMailer version do you use?

Comment: latest just downloaded it from github

Comment: try adding this like to you mail function `$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;`

Comment: Still showing SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. error message